# Eagle Change all part names (Designator)

Tags: eaglecad

I would like to change all my part numbers(Designator Name) one by one, but Eagle does not allow to change a component name with a name that already exists. So what is the fastest way to change all parts name?  (I already know about renumber ULP function but it does not let you pick your own name)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct way to do this, but there is a ULP which is helpful in this regard called: `swap.ulp`

With this you can simply enter commands in eagle such as:

```
run swap R1 R10
```

That would swap the names of R1 and R10 (R1 becomes R10, and R10 becomes R1).

If you have lots to do, you can use a text editor to make a list of the swaps required to map all of the part names into the desired ordering. You can then convert your list into `run swap a b` commands and run all of them.

Comment: Yes I have a lot of parts, so it is probably easier to write a script and then run it

Comment: One question when running this ulp it gives me an error: "Name '_TMP_' already exist!"

Comment: @Shahreza not sure - I use a modified version ([Uploaded here](https://gist.github.com/TCWORLD/10b0d251d896e97a0162208bd3c7ee4a)).